# nginx allows https inside server but not outside

Tags: python, django, nginx, https, waitress

I've a Django web app running using [Waitress](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/waitress/en/stable/runner.html) as a server. The server's firewall is set to allow HTTPS inbound traffic.

However, with the settings described below I cannot access the HTTPS site outside of the server itself. Yesterday I had no issue accessing the HTTP site just fine. This issue only occurred once I included the HTTPS settings.

*Am I missing something?*

The project's `settings.py` include

```
## SSL 
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

and the my project conf file includes

```
# Redirect all non-encrypted to encrypted
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name mysite.net; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name mysite.net;

    listen 443 ssl;  # <-

    ssl_certificate     C:/nginx-1.17.10/ssl/mysite_net.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     C:/nginx-1.17.10/ssl/mysite_net.key;

    access_log C:/nginx-1.17.10/logs/access.log;
    error_log C:/nginx-1.17.10/logs/error.log;


    location /static {
        alias C:/Users/batch_job/project/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        proxy_pass mysite.net:8001;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;  # <-
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;


    }
}
```

Comment: I know you said the firewall is set to allow HTTPS traffic, but this does seem like it could be a firewalling issue.

Comment: @Alasdair I know, right? I am not the owner of the VM so I cannot thoroughly inspect. But I’m general, do I need to allow inbound and outbound HTTPS traffic on a VM? I’m new to HTTPS projects